# Before update trigger: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER error

Tags: apex, trigger

> CreateOppLineItems: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 0066E000006s2Pi) is currently in trigger CreateOppLineItems, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: [] Trigger.CreateOppLineItems: line 102, column 1

```
trigger CreateOppLineItems on Opportunity (before update) {
    for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.New) {
        List<OpportunityLineItem> olil = new List <OpportunityLineItem>();
        String availableText = '';

        if (opp.Requested_Available_Versions__c == null && opp.Requested_available_digital_version__c != null) {
            availableText = opp.Requested_available_digital_version__c;
        } else if (opp.Requested_Available_Versions__c != null && opp.Requested_available_digital_version__c == null) {
            availableText = opp.Requested_Available_Versions__c;
        } else if (opp.Requested_Available_Versions__c != null && opp.Requested_available_digital_version__c != null) {
            availableText = opp.Requested_Available_Versions__c + '\n' + opp.Requested_available_digital_version__c;
        }
        if (availableText.contains('[') && opp.StageName == 'Initial Email Sent') {
            String prodStatus = '';
            String prodLogs = '';
            Integer totalAvailable = 0;
            Integer totalFailed = 0;

            // Loop Requested Available Versions
            String ravString = opp.Requested_Available_Versions__c;            
            if (ravString != null) {
                List<String> ravStringList = ravString.split('\\n');
                for (String s : ravStringList) {
                    totalAvailable+=1;
                    String prodId = s.substringBetween('[',']');
                    Product2[] objProdList = [SELECT Id, ProductId__c, IsActive FROM Product2 WHERE IsActive = true AND ProductId__c = :prodId];
                    String pid = '';
                    if (objProdList.size()>0) {
                        Product2 objProd = objProdList[0];
                        pid = objProd.Id;
                    }
                    if (pid != '' || pid != null) {
                        OpportunityLineItem[] objOliList = [SELECT Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2Id = :pid AND OpportunityId = :opp.Id];
                        String oliid = '';
                        if (objOliList.size()>0) {
                            OpportunityLineItem objOli = objOliList[0];
                            oliid = objOli.Id;
                        }
                        if (oliid != '' || oliid != null) {
                            OpportunityLineItem olinew = new OpportunityLineItem(Product2Id = pid,
                                                                                 OpportunityId = opp.Id,
                                                                                 ServiceDate = System.today(),                                                 
                                                                                 Quantity = 1,
                                                                                 TotalPrice = 0);
                            olil.add(olinew);
                        }
                    } else {
                        totalFailed+=1;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Loop Requested Available Digital Versions
            String radvString = opp.Requested_available_digital_version__c;            
            if (radvString != null) {
                List<String> radvStringList = radvString.split('\\n');
                for (String s : radvStringList) {
                    totalAvailable+=1;
                    String prodId = s.substringBetween('[',']');
                    Product2[] objProdList = [SELECT Id, ProductId__c, IsActive FROM Product2 WHERE IsActive = true AND ProductId__c = :prodId];
                    String pid = '';
                    if (objProdList.size()>0) {
                        Product2 objProd = objProdList[0];
                        pid = objProd.Id;
                    }                          
                    if (pid != '' || pid != null) {
                        OpportunityLineItem[] objOliList = [SELECT Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2Id = :pid AND OpportunityId = :opp.Id];
                        String oliid = '';
                        if (objOliList.size()>0) {
                            OpportunityLineItem objOli = objOliList[0];
                            oliid = objOli.Id;
                        }
                        if (oliid != '' || oliid != null) {
                            OpportunityLineItem olinew = new OpportunityLineItem(Product2Id = pid,
                                                                                 OpportunityId = opp.Id,
                                                                                 ServiceDate = System.today(),                                                 
                                                                                 Quantity = 1,
                                                                                 TotalPrice = 0);
                            olil.add(olinew);
                        }
                    } else {
                        totalFailed+=1;
                    }
                }

            }            

            if (totalFailed == 0) {
                prodStatus = '01-Successfully Created';
            } else {
                if (totalFailed == totalAvailable) {
                    prodStatus = '03-Failed';
                    prodLogs = 'Opportunity Product failed to be created.';
                } else {
                    prodStatus = '02- Partially Created';
                    prodLogs = 'Opportunity Product created with the Product Id and Opportunity product failed to be created with the Product Id.';
                }
            }
            //opp.Opportunity_Product_Status__c = prodStatus;
            //opp.Log__c = prodLogs;
        }
        insert olil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please use the editor tools to format your code (`{}` button), don't write in all capitals, and please ensure that your post contains a *clear, specific question*. See [ask] for more about our format, and please [edit] to make changes.

Comment: The question is bold because that is the exception given by the logs. Also I did my research, I did try the recursion class but still now working. I never had this issue with other class trigger creating a child object. That is why I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you're trying to update the opportunity recursively by creating new line items. This happens automatically, as the Amount field has to be updated when adding new line items. No "recursion blocker" will fix your problem, because the update happens automatically by the system.

In order to fix the problem, make sure you're only recursively updating the opportunity in an *after update* trigger:

```
trigger CreateOppLineItems on Opportunity (after update) {
```

You will likely need to make further changes to your trigger, but this one change will at least resolve the current error message.

Comment: Unfortunately if I use after update... I do also get this error.

CreateOppLineItems: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, CreateOppLineItems: maximum trigger depth exceeded Opportunity trigger event AfterUpdate Opportunity trigger event...

Comment: @user70826 Yes, I did say you'd need further revision. You need to write the trigger in a way that it checks for data changes, not just the current values. This should prevent infinite recursion.

Comment: Hi, I did manage to make it work by using Class to check recursion then adjusting the insert Opp Line items Outside the Recursion checking. Thanks